# Is anyone else getting this Bing Maps cert error?

Tags: certificate, bing-maps

Trying to debug a script problem with the Bing Maps Ajax API, but I'm running into a cert error when pulling in their script from this url:

https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0

Pretty sure the url is correct, but Chrome tells me the server is misidentified as *.vo.msecnd.net

Just me? Problems at Microsoft?

Comment: Yes dude! me too. Same error in firefox. It looks like their cert is bad. Now I know I'm not crazy

Comment: Me too! I also get a certificate error on https://www.bing.com/maps on FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I cheated but got our maps working using https again. Apparently MS has an invalid cert that may be back soon, but for production site needing maps this worked:

[hack]

1. Copy the script from the not https site: http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3
2. Host it on your https server , ex: /bing_maps_ohhh_no_what_happened/mapcontrol.js
3. Update your code to use the new url:

   ```
   //bingurl='https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3&s=1';
   bingurl = https://greatwebapp-really-it-is.yoursite/bing_maps_ohhh_no_what_happened/mapcontrol.js
   ```
4. Victory!!

[/hack]

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this question trying to load the mapcontrol using https:// in its url.

SeanDowney's answer helped me a lot, and I eventually found a more permanent solution (at least for our needs).

While the certs do seem messed up, my eventual solution was to add "&s=1" to the end of the mapcontrol.ashx url.